Weak derivative of a quotient
Let $w_1,w_2\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ with $p\in (1,\infty)$ such that $w_1,w_2>0$ a.e. on $\Omega$ and $\dfrac{w_1}{w_2},\dfrac{w_2}{w_1}\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. How can we prove that $\dfrac{w_1}{w_2}$ has a weak derivative and:
$$\nabla\left (\dfrac{w_1}{w_2} \right )=\dfrac{w_1\nabla w_2-w_2\nabla w_1}{w_2^2}.$$
My attempt was to consider the functions $w_{1,\epsilon}(x)=\begin{cases} \epsilon, w_1(x)\leq \epsilon\\ w_1(x), w_1(x)\in \left (\epsilon, \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \right )\\ \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}, w_1(x)\geq \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\end{cases}$ and $w_{2,\epsilon}(x)=\begin{cases} \epsilon, w_2(x)\leq \epsilon\\ w_2(x), w_2(x)\in \left (\epsilon, \dfrac{1}{\epsilon} \right )\\ \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}, w_2(x)\geq \dfrac{1}{\epsilon}\end{cases}$. We have that $w_{1,\epsilon}\to w_1$ and $w_{2,\epsilon}\to w_2$ pointwise. Moreover $w_{1,\epsilon},w_{2,\epsilon}\in W^{1,p}\cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. Also $\dfrac{w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}},\dfrac{w_{2,\epsilon}}{w_{1,\epsilon}}\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ (with bounds independent of $\epsilon$.
So we have that $\dfrac{w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}}\longrightarrow \dfrac{w_1}{w_2}$ pointwise. Being also bounded we deduce that $\dfrac{w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}}\longrightarrow \dfrac{w_1}{w_2}$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ from Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Moreover we easily get that $\dfrac{w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}}\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ (using product rule and chain rule for weak derivatives). Thus we have from the definition of the weak derivative:
$$\int_{\Omega} \dfrac{w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}}\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}\ dx=-\int_{\Omega}\phi\left [\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial w_{1,\epsilon}}{\partial x_i}w_{2,\epsilon}-\dfrac{\partial w_{2,\epsilon}}{\partial x_i}w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}^2}\right]\ dx$$
In the left hand side there is no problem when we take $\epsilon\to 0$. It converges to $\int_{\Omega} \dfrac{w_{1}}{w_2}\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}\ dx$. But in the right hand side although we have pointwise convergence it is hard for me to bound the function $\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial w_{1,\epsilon}}{\partial x_i}w_{2,\epsilon}-\dfrac{\partial w_{2,\epsilon}}{\partial x_i}w_{1,\epsilon}}{w_{2,\epsilon}^2}$ by a function from $L^1(\Omega)$ that is independent of $\epsilon$.
This is where I got stucked.

Take $\Omega = (0,1)$,
$$
w_1(x) = x \left( 2 + \sin( x^{-1/2}) \right), \ w_2(x) = x.
$$
Then $w_1 \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for $p \in [1,2)$,
$$
\frac{w_1}{w_2} \le 3, \ \frac{w_2}{w_1} \le 1.
$$
But
$$
\frac{w_1}{w_2} = 2 + \sin( x^{-1/2})
$$
has no integrable derivative.
